# How do i fix the multiplayer in this roblox lua script?

Tags: lua, scripting, roblox

My script only teleports and gives the tool to one player.
Even if I change the `i = 1` to a higher number it just starts the minigames with that amount of people and does the same thing as with `i = 1`.I have looked it up online and I have asked other developers I know and they couldn’t fix it so I’m asking you guys.
Please try and help me...

```lua
while true do 
  wait(5) 
  local m = math.random(1,6)
  local g = math.random(1,4)
  local player = game.Players:GetChildren()
  for i = 1, #player do 
    msg = Instance.new("Message") 
    msg.Parent = nil 
    --Minigame1
    msg.Parent = game.Workspace 
    msg.Text = "Choosing Map."
    wait(0.5)
    msg.Text = "Choosing Map.."
    wait(0.5)
    msg.Text = "Choosing Map..."
    wait(0.5)
    msg.Text = "Choosing Map."
    wait(0.5)
    msg.Text = "Choosing Map.."
    wait(0.5)
    msg.Text = "Choosing Map..."
    wait(0.5)
    msg.Text = "Choosing Map."
    wait(0.5)
    msg.Text = "Choosing Map.."
    wait(0.5)
    msg.Text = "Choosing Map..."
    wait(0.5)
    msg.Text = "Map Number" ..m.. "!!!" 
    wait(3)
    msg.Text = game.Lighting.Minigames["Minigame"..m].MapName.Value
    wait(3)
    msg.Text = game.Lighting.Minigames["Minigame"..m].Description.Value
    wait(3)
    game.Lighting.Minigames["Minigame"..m]:clone().Parent = game.Workspace 
    wait(3)
    player[i].Character:MoveTo(Vector3.new(-24.19, 1, -14.69))
    msg.Text = "Choosing Minigame."
    wait(0.5)
    msg.Text = "Choosing Minigame.."
    wait(0.5)
    msg.Text = "Choosing Minigame..."
    wait(0.5)
    msg.Text = "Choosing Minigame."
    wait(0.5)
    msg.Text = "Choosing Minigame.."
    wait(0.5)
    msg.Text = "Choosing Minigame..."
    wait(0.5)
    msg.Text = "Choosing Minigame."
    wait(0.5)
    msg.Text = "Choosing Minigame.."
    wait(0.5)
    msg.Text = "Choosing Minigame..."
    wait(0.5)
    msg.Text = game.Lighting.Minigames["Minigame"..m]["Mode"..g].Value
    wait(2)
    msg.Text = game.Lighting.Minigames["Minigame"..m]["ModeDescription"..g].Value
    wait(5)
    msg:remove() 
    game.Lighting.Minigames["Minigame"..m]["Tool"..g]:Clone().Parent = 
    player[i].Backpack
    wait(60)
    msg.Parent = game.Workspace
    msg.Text = "GAME END"
    wait(3)
    player[i].Character:MoveTo(Vector3.new(-168.742, 148.7, -26.169))
    msg:remove() 
    game.Workspace["Minigame"..m]:Destroy() 
    if player[i].Backpack:FindFirstChild("Tool1") or 
        player[i].Backpack:FindFirstChild("Tool2") or 
        player[i].Backpack:FindFirstChild("Tool3") or 
        player[i].Backpack:FindFirstChild("Tool4") then
      player[i].Backpack.Tool1:Remove()  
      player[i].Backpack.Tool2:Remove()
      player[i].Backpack.Tool3:Remove()
      player[i].Backpack.Tool4:Remove()
    end
    if player[i].Character:FindFirstChild("Tool"..g) then
      player[i].Character.Tool1:Destroy()
      player[i].Character.Tool2:Destroy()
      player[i].Character.Tool3:Destroy()
      player[i].Character.Tool4:Destroy()
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: so when you have 10 players in your list and you start with i = 5 you still have 10 players? What is "that amount" I'm confused

Comment: You waited the full minute and a half for the loop to reach the second player, I assume?

Comment: Yes you would still have 10 players, the amount is the amount of players needed for the game to start, and yes aschepler

Comment: Please be a bit more specific in what a) should happen and b) is actually happening :)

Comment: I can't help but think you just got the entire loop wrong; do you really want to run the entire script from begining to end for one player at a time?

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot of problems with this script, but I'm only going to focus on the ones which immediately help your problem - if you want to clean up your code, head to [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

```lua
local player = game.Players:GetChildren()
--code here
for i = 1, #player do
  player[i].Character:MoveTo(Vector3.new(-24.19, 1, -14.69))
  game.Lighting.Minigames["Minigame"..m]["Tool"..g]:Clone().Parent = 
  player[i].Backpack
end
--more code would go here
for i = 1, #player do
  player[i].Character:MoveTo(Vector3.new(-168.742, 148.7, -26.169))
  if player[i].Backpack:FindFirstChild("Tool1") or 
      player[i].Backpack:FindFirstChild("Tool2") or 
      player[i].Backpack:FindFirstChild("Tool3") or 
      player[i].Backpack:FindFirstChild("Tool4") then
    player[i].Backpack.Tool1:Remove()  
    player[i].Backpack.Tool2:Remove()
    player[i].Backpack.Tool3:Remove()
    player[i].Backpack.Tool4:Remove()
  end
  if player[i].Character:FindFirstChild("Tool"..g) then
    player[i].Character.Tool1:Destroy()
    player[i].Character.Tool2:Destroy()
    player[i].Character.Tool3:Destroy()
    player[i].Character.Tool4:Destroy()
  end
end
```

This is the only content that should be in `for` loops. The rest should only be ran once, and as such, shouldn't be inside a for loop - therefore, I've added comments where the rest of your code should be (for the sake of space) and only left the content that should be looped.

Your problem is that you're running all the messages and `wait` commands for every player individually. Depending on the number of the players in the game, you'd have multiple loops, but none of them would run at the same time, so you'd go through your entire script for player 1, then player 2, then player 3. Since your game seems to have rounds that only last 60 seconds, it means that player 1 gets tools for a round, then player 2 gets tools for a round, then player 3 gets tools for a round, etc.

If you move all of those out of the loops like I have above, and just leave the parts which move the players and destroy their tools (but don't add them? seems like missing code), the code should function just fine.

Comment: im confused i dont have alot of knowledge of coding and i dont understand what you mean please try and make it easier for me to understand...sorry

Comment: You currently loop this script for every player in the game. However, you run all of the scripts that start the minigame in that loop. So, your game currently runs a minigame with `i = 1` meaning player 1 gets all of the tools, then runs a minigame with `i = 2` meaning player 2 gets all of the tools, and so on.

To fix this, take everything relevant to the minigame except the tools and positions, and move them outside the loop, leaving only the important parts inside the loop. That's what my script above has done.

Comment: IM SOO CONFUSED SORRY!

Comment: I've commented my changes to your code at https://repl.it/@TehDindan/code-for-robloxdevnewbie which should now make it work for the reasons I've explained above. Hopefully, this helps you understand what's wrong with your code, referring to this answer as well..

Comment: will it still loop the script and have a continuous game?

Comment: Okay i tried it out and it still only teleports one player and gives the tool to one player

Comment: Confusing. Have you defined `game.Players` anywhere? Looks to me as if you haven't, so there's no table for `player[i]` to read from. Perhaps using `game:GetService("Players"):GetPlayers()` would work better in its place.